# In Canada, are Safeway and Thrifty Foods owned by the same company?

Tags: law

In Canada, are Safeway and Thrifty Foods owned by the same company? I find this hard to believe but was told this by an employee who worked at Safeway.

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobeys) here it seems Thrifty Foods is owned by Sobeys who bought out the Canadian chain of Safeway, so I guess the answer is yes?

> In June 2013, Sobeys announced the purchase of Safeway's Canadian
>   operations for $5.8 billion, subject to regulatory approval. The
>   acquisition will add Safeway's 214 locations, primarily located in
>   Western Canada, to its portfolio. Sobeys has not yet determined
>   whether it will maintain the Safeway brand post-acquisition.[5] In
>   August 2013, Sobeys sold the land under 68 Safeways to Crombie REIT
>   for $900 million.

Comment: I see your surprise, but I am not sure I see skepticism. Do you doubt the Wikipedia summary and/or its sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to start off, [Sobey's is the owner of Thrifty Foods, as confirmed by their about page](https://www.sobeys.com/en).

[Sobey's did buy Safeway](http://business.financialpost.com/2013/11/04/sobeys-completes-5-8-billion-purchase-of-safeway/), for $5.8Bn in 2013, however [their website](https://www.sobeys.com/en) doesn't list it amongst their brands (see the footer), and various business news articles mention the selling of [Safeway stores](http://www.cbc.ca/news/business/sobeys-to-sell-23-stores-in-safeway-deal-1.2159468) following intervention by the Competition Bureau in Canada.

Basic conclusion:  Sobey's do indeed own both, but the acquistion of Safeway led to unforeseen regulatory problems, that may change the situation somewhat.

Comment: Almost all of the "have to sell" Safeway stores have been sold already (as of last week).  22 out of the 23 were sold to the Federated Cooperatives.  I know because one of the stores sold is in my city.  Sale of the 23rd one to someone else is currently pending.